# PayTm :Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, payment-gateway, paytm

In my project i am trying to implement PayTm payment gateway. I import all the required files and library to my app. but now i am trying to navigate to payTm page it gives the following error and app crashes.

i am using the following code:

```
- (IBAction)submitAction:(id)sender
{
    //[self CallWebservice];
    //[self methodForChrckSumHash];

    //Step 1: Create a default merchant config object
    PGMerchantConfiguration *mc = [PGMerchantConfiguration defaultConfiguration];

    //Step 2: Create the order with whatever params you want to add. But make sure that you include the merchant mandatory params
    NSMutableDictionary *orderDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    //Merchant configuration in the order object
    orderDict[@"MID"] = @"Natur******";
    orderDict[@"ORDER_ID"] = @"****11008";
    orderDict[@"CUST_ID"] = @"0012";
    orderDict[@"INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = @"Retail";
    orderDict[@"CHANNEL_ID"] = @"WAP";
    orderDict[@"TXN_AMOUNT"] = @"0";
    orderDict[@"WEBSITE"] = @"WEB_STAGING";
    orderDict[@"CALLBACK_URL"] = @"http://www.**********.in/new/paytm/pgResponse.php";
    orderDict[@"CHECKSUMHASH"] = @"*****************zvBRbqTfastx07J5HucJ9jIodi42YWqSdQCk2g45ESsp9WvHnbkoVob718=";
    orderDict[@"MERCHANT_KEY"] = @"**********";


    PGOrder *order = [PGOrder orderWithParams:orderDict];


    [PGServerEnvironment selectServerDialog:self.view completionHandler:^(ServerType eServerTypeProduction)
     {
         PGTransactionViewController *txnController = [[PGTransactionViewController alloc] initTransactionForOrder:order];

         //txnController.merchant = [PGMerchantConfiguration defaultConfiguration];

         txnController.serverType = eServerTypeProduction;
         txnController.merchant = mc;
         txnController.delegate = self;
         txnController.loggingEnabled = YES;
         [self showController:txnController];

     }];
}
```

with these parameters now i am getting the following Response

> [5890:352298] ViewController::didFailTransaction error = Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with
>   array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.} response= (null)

Comment: From what I guess, you did `txnController.delegate = self;`. Your payment failed (for n reason), and then `txnController` wanted to tell its `delegate` (which is `self`) it failed, but you didn't implement a REQUIRED delegate method (you should have a warning by the way), according to this https://github.com/samyam-a/PayTM-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/src/ios/PayTM/Headers/PGTransactionViewController.h  You need to code `- (void)didFailTransaction:(PGTransactionViewController *)controller error:(NSError *)error response:(NSDictionary *)response;`

Comment: thanks now it gives the following response ViewController::didFailTransaction error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: I'm not familiar with Payment Gateway. It says that if failed because the response (who manages it? You? The Payment Gateway lib?) wasn't JSON.

Comment: the payment gateway library manage it

Comment: Did you figure it out?